# Change color of element on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed header with a logo and some text. Those elements are currently white. (background-color: #fff)

While I scroll down sections appear with different background colors:

```
white
black
black
white
green
etc.
```

I want to change the color of the elements in the header depending on the section the header is currently above. I could do it with mixblend mode (white/black) but i also have green sections. I could also do it by check what section is in view and then change the color.

But I was wondering if there is some kind of a way to get the element that is currently below the header (a div that is below a div) via javascript. By below i my visually like z-index below.

If so, I could also get the css styles of the element.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check this pen: https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV

Comment: Could you put up an example of your HTML structure. Also when exactly do you want the color of the header elements to change - is it when the top of a section is in the viewport or is it the section that is (partially) right up against the bottom of the header?

Comment: Here's a pen with what you've described: https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/eYgomzy?editors=1111

Comment: @PaulMartin this is exactly what i want to achieve. However I dont know the heights of the containers. They differ based on the content. If you listen to mousemove you get the element the mouse is currenlty over. I would like to know it something like this also exist for div over div (header over containers) instead of calculating the offset of the containers.

Comment: You could do...
let firstHeight = document.getElementById("1").offsetHeight
...to get the height of each element, then do...
if (userScroll > first && userScroll < (first + firstHeight)){

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `document`'s [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) event for this.

Then, with `window`'s `pageYOffset` and `scrollMaxY` you can determine how far you scrolled.

```js
var maxOffset = window.scrollMaxY;
function onScroll(event) {
  let offset = window.pageYOffset;
  let color = "#"+(Math.round(offset/maxOffset*9))+"00000";

  document.getElementById("example").style = "color:"+color+";";
  
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

```html
<p id="example" style="foreground-color:#FF0000">Color!</p>
```